# Error while accessing proxy from emulator 2.2

Tags: android

08-19 00:20:45.512: ERROR/System(51): java.lang.SecurityException
08-19 00:20:45.512: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
08-19 00:20:45.512: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
08-19 00:20:45.512: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
08-19 00:20:45.512: ERROR/System(51):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)

This is the error log from logcat.

The AndroidManifest.xml file has internet access permission.

What am I missing? Please help I am going nuts!

I am trying to connect to a proxy server from the emulator. I have specified the proxy server in the emulator with the ip address. But everytime I try to access anything from the emulator I get the error above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a proxy while in the emulator, use the command line argument `-http-proxy 10.5.0.1:8888` when starting the emulator. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html).

Comment: Hey thanks for responding but this is not working. I am getting the error above.